# Uploading Multiple files in form to server PHP and put Information in a Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

A song is uploaded to a server that also injects data to database using php form and mysql. This works great for one file, but there will be 3 separate files to upload. The goal is to have each file upload to the server and post the data into mysql. When I try to upload it gives me the error. I believe it is something to do with how i added the multiple files. Here is what I have so far:

Edit: I have messed with it some more and this is what I got, The problem is with having multiple move_uploaded_files. I was reading where you can do the loop array, but I am adding theese into a mys

**Upload Page Form**

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>  
B.P.M.: <input type="text" name = "bpm"><br>  
Length: <input type="text" name = "length"><br> 
Keywords: <input type="text" name = "keywords"><br>  
Tagged MP3: <input type="file" name="downloadlink"><br>  
MP3: <input type="file" name="mp3link"><br>  
WAV: <input type="file" name="wavlink"><br>  
<input type="submit" value="Add">  
</form>
```

**add.php (second page)**

```
    <?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
$uploads_dir = 'beats/';
foreach ($_FILES[""]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES[""]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES[""]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $bpm=$_POST['bpm'];
 $length=$_POST['length'];
 $keywords=$_POST['keywords']; 
 $downloadlink=($_FILES['downloadlink']['name']); 
 $mp3link=($_FILES['mp3link']['name']); 
 $wavlink=($_FILES['wavlink']['name']); 



 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("exclusive") or die(mysql_error()) ; 


//Writes the information to the database 
 $date = date('m-d-Y');
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO exclusive VALUES ('', '$date', '$name', '$bpm', '$length', '$keywords', '$downloadlink', '$mp3link', '$wavlink')") ; 

 ?>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Sulthan Allaudeen Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file. plus no entry into database

Comment: Can you replace `echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";` with  `echo mysql_error();` and tell what it says ?

Comment: well, you can't use this syntax `$_FILES['downloadlink, mp3link, wavlink']` - I suggest you Google "upload multiple files php". You'll find many results, I am 100% certain of it. Use error reporting, you'll see the real error. Go to PHP.net's website; there's an example in there you can use and base yourself on.

Comment: You need to use move_uploaded_file three times (separete for each file)

Comment: And you kept replacing `$target` with different values.

Comment: See Example #1 Uploading multiple files in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note when you are uploading multiple files to a database is to make sure your php.ini file's upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are set to handle a large enough amount. One reason this was not working is because mine was set to small.

Here is the working Code:

**Form (whateveryouwantupload.html)**

```
<form action="addmulti.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p> 
<p>B.P.M.: <input type="text" name = "bpm"></p>
<p>Length: <input type="text" name = "length"></p> 
<p>Keywords: <input type="text" name = "keywords"></p>
  <p>Tagged MP3: <input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p>MP3: <input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p>WAV: <input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload all files">
</form>
```

**PHP (addmulti.php)**

```
<?php
// Multiple Upload Files
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];

//Get Form Information 
 $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $bpm=$_POST['bpm'];
 $length=$_POST['length'];
 $keywords=$_POST['keywords']; 
 $downloadlink=$name_array[0]; 
 $mp3link=$name_array[1]; 
 $wavlink=$name_array[2]; 

 // Connect to Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("exclusive") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

//Writes the information to the database 
            $date = date('m-d-Y');
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('', '$date', '$name', '$bpm', '$length', '$keywords', '$downloadlink', '$mp3link', '$wavlink')") ;

//Writes file to server
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){     
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "testupload/".$name_array[$i])){

            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**php.ini**

```
max_execution_time = 300
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

Thanks for the help!